# Add class in HTML with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with email and password validation. When password is wrong the box *password* has to be red to show that something go wrong, i do that adding a `"vermei"` class.

I have to do this in PHP, already attempted:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$input=$dom->getElementById('password');
foreach($input as $pd){
    $pd->setAttribute('class', $pd->getAttribute('class').' vermei');
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML(); // return 'variable $html not found'
```

and

```
echo '<script>
        alert("Password Incorrect!");
        history.go(-1); //work until this part, the code below do not run. 
 //I did this go back cuz when form is submitted, go to config.php, and
 // this code back to sign in page
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        document.getElementById("password").focus();
        password.classList.add("vermei");
    </script>';
```

Someone can help me with adding a `"vermei"` class in Password input?

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: `getElementById` just returns a single element, not a list. You don't need the loop.

Comment: @daremachine both codes does not add a ```vermei``` class to html, and nothing happen

Comment: `$dom->loadHTML($html);` — You're using the `$html` variable there … so where is it defined? Why are you manipulating an entire HTML document instead of using PHP as a template language and `echo`ing anyway?

Comment: Neither of these approaches make sense to me.  In the first approach you appear to be *overwriting an HTML file*, when and why would you be doing that?  And in the second approach you immediately redirect the user back to the previous page, so any code running after that is moot.  Where are you performing the validation of the password input?  It's not clear to me what the overall logic flow is here.  But how you update the UI is going to entirely depend on that.

Comment: As an aside... If this is a login form then you shouldn't tell them *which input* was incorrect.  All the user should know is that the login failed.  Telling them that the username was correct but the password was not gives an attacker information.  Not much information, and potentially something they could get otherwise, but it's best not to get into the habit of giving information to unauthenticated users.

Comment: @David thanks for the warning and guidance, will go learn with these answers and remake my code.

Comment: @Quentin i solved this part, not that the rest is right, but i fixed this part at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code doesn't work because `$input` is a single element, not a list, so you can't loop over it. Replace the loop with just:

```
$input->setAttribute("class", $input->getAttribute("class") . " vermei");
```

Normally you would do this in the code that outputs the form, e.g.

```
<form>
    ...
    Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password" <?php if ($password_incorrect) echo 'class="vermei"'; ?>>
    ...
</form>
```